# Code Behind Manipulations/Giving custom names to Variables/Combining names

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

So my problem goes, like, I want to have dynamic seted names, something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            CheckBox i = new CheckBox();


        }
```

2 bad it does not work ^^
Is it even possible to get values like that from variables, and transform them into variables names? Or should I just set thoes things staticly?

Ow yeah and afeter setting something like that I would like to do something like this to set the content, bascily it will go in the same loop

fe. i want to have 5 buttons and i have made 5 strings in the AppResources, their names goes like : a0,a1,a2,a3,a4;

So now I'm creating the buttons and using the content.

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            CheckBox i = new CheckBox();
            i.Content = Resources.AppResources.a+"i";


        }
```

So, anyone can help?^^

Comment: dude, Im not familiar with Windows Phone 8, but I guess it must be the same (XAML-based) as WPF/WinRT. Why are you creating UI elements in code? that's completely wrong. Post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you a way to do it in XAML.

Comment: So you suggest that I should create UI elements in xaml file and eventually managing them from the codebehind?

Comment: nope, I mean that, in XAML-based UIs, you don't "manage" the UI, you pass in the proper data and let the UI handle it via Bindings.

Comment: well i cant post the images atm i need 10 reputation :D

Comment: http://pokazywarka.pl/9j2aq0/   here the link to the page with the images, I'm doing it in this way atm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an array:

```
ArrayList<CheckBox> checkboxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    checkboxes.Add(new CheckBox());
}
```

Comment: The list thing was a thing I thought about , thou it does solve the problem but know problem goes further, about the content and getting variables from AppResources for ea of them